# How to use jQuery UI with Play Scala

Tags: jquery-ui, scala, playframework-2.0

I'm looking to do a Play Scala project where I'll do especially **drag & drop**.

Is jQuery UI the best and the simplest way to do that? and How could one do this? could someone give me some examples or pointers?

In Play 1.0 there is a good example on how to use jQuery UI (http://www.playframework.com/modules/jqueryui-1.0/home) but I don't found examples or documentation on Play2.0 Scala !

Comment: No surprise there. jQuery is a client side technology and has absolutely zit to do with the server side scala templates.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need to define an endpoint for your data in the controller.

Simething like this:

```
def autocompleteSearch(a: String) = Action {
    request =>
      val data = List("apple", "apple iphone", "apple ipad", "microsoft windows", "microsot office");
      val filteredData = data.filter(_.startsWith(a))
      Ok(Json.toJson(filteredData))
  }
```

Then you need to add this endpoint to your routes:

```
GET  /some-ajax                    controllers.Application.autocompleteSearch
```

Then in your .scala.html file you can write a script that will do a get you you, example:

```
var updateTime = function() {
    $.get("@routes.Application.timeUpdate()", function(data) {
        display.html(data)
    })
    return false
    }
```

When you have the var you just pass it to the jQueryUI.

My examples are copied from different things and they don't really fit together :) but I hope you can grasp the general idea.

Sorry the answer is not more specific, but I'm no JavaScript master and had to fight with the jQuery once, and this is what I have left from the struggle.

Cheers!